# How to determine a Matrix of an endomorphism $f$ in a standard Base $B$ of a Vector space $E$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

*I am trying to get the pattern in solving such questions dealing with vector space.
I understand what a base, a vector space but when it comes to determine the underneath Matrix I am stuck.*

We consider the vector space $ E= R_2[x]$ with it's standard base $B_E=(1, X, X^2)$ and f the endomorphism of $E$ defined by :
$ f(P)=(8X-2)P^{"}(-2)+(3x^2-7)P^{'}(-1)+1P$

**Question** :  Determine the Matrix $ \begin{equation*}
 Mat_{B_E}(f) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$

Comment: You need to express the images under $f$ of the basis elements,  $1,x ,x^2$ in terms of the basis elements again.   Those will be your columns.

Comment: So, $f(1)=1$.  So the first column is $(1,0,0)^t$.

Comment: Should I carry on with f(x) and $f(x^2)$ and so on. then . right!  But what's about P'(-1) In this case?

Comment: For instance,  if $P=x$, then $P'=1$.  Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column is $(1,0,0)^t$, as I commented.

For the second, we express $f(x)=3x^2+x-7$ in the basis,  and get $(3,1,-7)^t$.

Finally,  $f(x^2)=(8x-2)(2)+(3x^2-7)(-2)+x^2=4x^2+16x+10$.  So the third is $(4,16,10)^t$.

Comment: I was confused by that P'(-2), I thought I have to substitute values after deriving  P. I was just a multiplication .  Thanks

Comment: If $P'(x)=c$ is constant, then $P'(-1)=c$.  Sure.